# Can i deploy multiple logic apps using Release Definition to Particular environment?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have to deploy 5 logic apps to Azure app resource group using one task : Azure Resource Group Deployment.

> Name of the each logic app's Template File is : **LogicApp.Json** 
> Name of
>   the each logic app's Template parameter File is :
>   **LogicApp.parameters.$(environment).Json**

Naming convention is same for all logic app files except each one is within its own folder. 
**Release Task is failing : Not able to find matching pattern :**
[image]

Is it possible in one task or do i have to create multiple tasks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  But it depends on what exactly you mean by 'release pipeline'.

You can either deploy multiple template/parameter files, one for each Logic App.

Or, merge all your Logic App definitions into one template file.

To deploy multiple anything in one operation on the Portal, you will need to merge all the definitions into one file.

Comment: I mean i have created release definition for DEV environment where i want to deploy all logic apps using one task i.e. Azure Resource Group Deployment. Task

Comment: @SagarK Sure...the Answer is the same though.

Comment: In single file using task or i have to manually create such file

Comment: @SagarK To deploy multiple anything in one action on the Portal, you will have to merge them into one template file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @SagarK It's helpful tp upvote or mark any helpful Answer.